# URL Rewriting Issue in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, redirect, url-rewrite-module

I have a requirement as follows...

We have a page called prodSpecification.aspx which accepts few parameters like id and category etc.

The user can do a search for a product which will display them the products. Clicking on a product will call the above page prodSpecification.aspx with the required parameters.

In order to make the URL SEO friendly, we want to change the above URL as follows.

www.xyz.com/prodSpecification.aspx?modelID=4004&cond=all

TO

​www.xyz.com/{Manufacturer}/{ProductGroup}/{BaseModel}/

but behind the scenes, the user will be taken to www.xyz.com/prodSpecification.aspx?modelID=4004&cond=all. The URL change is only for the user and SEO.URL.

Is this possible. All examples and readings I see is the other way round...

Any help will be appreciated..

Anup

Answer (score 0):

If you're using asp.net version 4 or greater, use the built-in [URL routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series).  If you're unfortunate enough to be using an older version, you can use the [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module).

Comment: Updated question......
When the user clicks on a product from the application, we create a clean URL like {Manufacturer}/{ProductGroup}/{BaseModel} and in the global.asax, register routes as routes.MapPageRoute("", {Manufacturer}/{ProductGroup}/{BaseModel}/true/1/all", "~/ViewProduct.aspx"). This works.

Now when the user tries to browse directly from the browser as www.xyz.com/ViewProduct.aspx?modelID=4004&cond=all, we will need to change the URL to www.xyz.com/{Manufacturer}/{ProductGroup}/{BaseModel}.Is this possible?